# Laravel Collection returns only 11 values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections

I'm building timeline for my app and got this issue, that my collection returns me only 11 values. 
I have tried to change merged data and it always returns me 11 values that makes me very confused, bc their is no limits in my code.

```
public function timeline($company_id)
{
    // USER COMPANY
    $company = auth()->user()->companies()->findOrFail($company_id);

    //GETTING DATA TO MERGE COLLECTION
    $equities = Share::where('company_id', $company_id)->get();
    $equityGrants = EquityGrant::whereIn('share_id', $equities->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
    $warrants = Warrant::where('company_id', $company_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
    $warrantGtrants = WarrantGrant::whereIn('warrant_id', $warrants->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
    $convertibles = Convertible::where('company_id', $company_id)->get();

    // CREATING COLLECTION
    $operations = $equities->merge($equityGrants)->merge($warrants)->merge($warrantGtrants)->merge($convertibles);
    $operations  = $operations->sortByDesc('created_at');

    // RETURNS ME ONLY 11 VALUES
    return $operations->values()->all();
}
```

I tried to `merge()` less instances, like `$operations = $equities->merge($equityGrants)->merge($warrants)->merge($warrantGtrants)` but always maximum 11 values.  I need to return all data for my timeline.

HELP ME Please! :)
Cheers, love :)

SOLUTION:
function concat() instead of merge() fixed the problem.

Comment: try dd($operations), how many items do you have there?

Comment: 11 only, as I noted above. Even if I change my collection, still show only 11 items

Answer (score 1):

Using merge() on collections in Laravel will cause overiding all elements with the same ids comming from Eloquent query.

I believe that is why you are getting only 11 elements because this is the count off all elements having distinct ids.

Comment: This is looks like truth, probably yes, merge limits my data by `id`. Any ideas how to avoid it?

Comment: Why don't you try push() all the collections to a new collection?

Comment: you can use a base collection to merge into ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534929/how-to-merge-two-collections-without-dropping-losing-keys-in-laravel-php-frame#51535251

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-merge), when a key matches, it will be overwritten by the last item with that key (the collection you are merging in).

A solution to your problem would be the `keyBy` method ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-keyby)). If you use `keyBy('created_at')`, it will give you an array where the keys are the `created_at` timestamps.

Although it sounds like they would be unique, there is a great change that some of the linked resources (like `warrant` and `warrentGrants`) are created at the exact same moment. If that is the case, you should try to find another key or something that is unique across all resources.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: function concat() instead of merge() fixed the problem.