# Laravel retrieve multiple relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel project where a `User` can have many `Client` class. The `Client` can have many `Session` and and a `Session` can have many `Assessment` and many `Plan`. I am using hasManyThrough on the `Client` to get `Assessment` and `Plan`. Each `Assessment` and `Plan` has a `review_date` timestamp saved into the database.

What I'd like to do is get all the `Assessment` and `Plan` for any `Client` with their `review_date` as today. Ideally something like:

```
$events = Auth::user()->reviews()->today();
```

What I don't know how to do it make the `reviews` function, because it's essentially combining 2 relationships.

Can anyone help me out?

```
User.php

public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Client::class);
}

public function assessments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Assessment::class, Client::class);
}

public function plans()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Plan::class, Client::class);
}

public function reviews()
{
    // return all assessments and plans
}

public function scopeToday(Builder $query)
{
    $query->whereDate('review_date', Carbon::today());
}
```

```
Client.php

public function assessments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Assessment::class, Session::class);
}

public function plans()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Plan::class, Session::class);
}
```

```
Session.php

public function assessments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Assessment::class);
}

public function plans()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Plan::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a collection from both methods, so you could simply [merge the 2 together](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge). (Be warned, this will lead to ugly code later when you have to check object types during the loop.) You can't chain the scope method, since you aren't getting back a relationship object, but you could pass the date as a parameter instead, or just fix it at today's date if you'll never need other dates.

```php
public function reviews(Carbon $date)
{
    return $this
        ->assessments()
        ->whereDate('review_date', $date)
        ->get()
        ->toBase()
        ->merge(
            $this->plans()->whereDate('review_date', $date)->get()->toBase()
        )
        ->sortBy('review_date');
}
```

And then call it like this:

```php
$date = now();
$events = Auth::user()->reviews($date);
```

Comment: if you merge 2 different eloquent collections you potentially could be losing records since it builds a dictionary keyed by the key of the models and both collections could have models with the same ids

Comment: Documentation for `merge()` says it's an append for numeric keys. Model collections aren't keyed by primary key. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge

Comment: Eloquent Collections are extended from Collections and override certain methods, like `merge`, because they use a dictionary that is keyed by the primary key of the model ... its in the code, `Eloquent\Collection@merge` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L329   `Eloquent\Collection@getDictionary` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L531  "Get a dictionary keyed by primary keys" ... they have different behavior than the base Collection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534929/how-to-merge-two-collections-without-dropping-losing-keys-in-laravel-php-frame/51535251#51535251

Comment: Hmm that's good to know, I've updated the answer. There seem to be some inconsistencies with Eloquent collections, like `Model::all()[1]` returning the second item in the collection, regardless of ID, or `Model::all()->toArray()` returning a non-sparse array.

Comment: they are not keyed by id, the dictionary that is keyed by primary key is used internally for certain things, like merging, since an eloquent Collection would usually only be holding 1 type of model so duplicates are not needed ... the array function equivalents use this dictionary; but if you look at the return of `merge` it is calling `array_values` to create the new collection instance (so its not keyed by primary key like the dictionary uses)

Comment: Understood, it just seems inconsistent that there would be essentially 2 different sets of keys for the collection.

Comment: yea its one of those nuances ... it makes sense why it would use the dictionary internally for certain things but yea from the outside all other interactions are based on the normal index ... i hear ya on that man (lots of people have stumbled across this one and not had a fun time with it)

Comment: i like the answer, i just wanted to warn of the potentially problem that one could run into with that one thing, so thanks for listening and adjusting that; having them avoiding future problems is the only reason i said anything ... side note: didn't want to edit your answer but you used the word 'buy' instead of 'but' in one sentence `;-)` ... have a great day